# VF component attribute control outputPanel rendered

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, rendered

I have the following VF component,

```
<apex:component layout="none" selfClosing="true">
<apex:attribute name="label" description="This is pretty name for this input" type="String" required="true"/>
<apex:attribute name="location" type="String" description="Field Name" required="true" />
<apex:attribute name="inputObject" description="Object Name" type="sObject" required="true" />
<apex:attribute name="inputFieldName" description="Field Name" type="String" required="true" />

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!location == "left"}">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{!label}</label>
  <div class="col-md-6 form-control-wrapper">
    <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!inputObject[inputFieldName]}"/>
    <span class="material-input"></span>
  </div>
</div>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

What I want to know is if `!location` is left, right or middle. Depending on the incoming string I want to display a different panel (currently not built). I have also tried `rendered="{!IF(!location == "left", true, false)}"` but that did not work. The problem is that I get this error message,

> The element type "apex:outputPanel" must be terminated by the matching
>   end-tag ""

How can I control the rendered `IF String1 == String2`?

Comment: Did you try using single quote for "left"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is as below

```
rendered="{!IF(location == 'left', true, false)}"
```